# Function to lowercase and concatenate with underscores

Tags: emacs

I want to change a marked region of text to all **lower-case** words concatenated by **underscores**. For example:

```
A fox caught a bird => a_fox_caught_a_bird
```

What is the function in **Emacs** 23?

Answer (score 7):

There is no built-in function that does what you want, but this snippet will do the trick.

```
(defun lower-and-concat (b e)
  (interactive "r")
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region b e)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (downcase-region b e)
    (while (re-search-forward "[ \t]+" nil t)
      (replace-match "_"))))
```